# Can SVG "pssthru" events to an element behind it - but only for half the SVG?

Tags: svg

I have two SVG tags like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 300px">
    <div id="cc1" style="width: 700px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0"><svg width="700" height="300" version="1.1"></svg></div>
    <div id="cc2" style="width: 700px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0"><svg width="700" height="300" version="1.1"></svg></div>
</div>
```

So like this (two  tags, each nested in a div, all nested in a container div):

```
<div>
    <div>  <svg></svg>  </div>
    <div>  <svg></svg>  </div>
</div>
```

I'm drawing the top half of a chart on the top svg tag and the bottom half on the bottom svg tag (in a different color). It works fine - except when it comes to events. Because the first svg tag is behind the second svg tag it doesn't respond to pointer-events.

Is there a way to make the CSS pointer-events property only apply to half of an element (in this case - half the svg tag)? Or some other way to make the top half of my svg tag 'invisible' to pointer events so that the event is passed to the svg tag at the rear?

Comment: You can __ make an svg tag 'invisible' to pointer events __ by using `pointer-events: none;` in CSS or as an attribute. If this is not helping you try adding more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer based on a StackOverflow post 5 minutes after posting the question.

Wrap the second, "top" (stacking-wise), SVG tag in another div and position it so the top of the SVG tag is -150px and set the overflow to hidden:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 300px">
    <div id="cc1" style="width: 700px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0">  <svg></svg>  </div>
    
    <!-- The second svg tag is positioned so that the top half is hidden -->
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 0; width: 700px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden">
        <div id="cc2" style="width: 700px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: -150px; left: 0">  <svg></svg>   </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The resulting chart: https://codepen.io/rgraph/full/yLjxzJy